# Android multi-threading download n number of resources in background

Tags: java, android, multithreading, round-robin

I am developing an android app, where initially it downloads all apps resources form server and saves in data folder, where the download occurs in background. When user navigates between fragments containing gridview, downloaded resources will show in grid item (imageview) else it shows loading circle indicating resources are in download state.

Here's how i designed the download manager.

Using ThreadPoolExecuter to create 4 threads and PriorityBlockingQueue with default size. Each thread has a queue of size 5. Here round robin function will check each threads queue and adds task to the thread which has free queue space.

Could someone help me achieve above requirement by giving pointers, sample pseudo code like example.

I implemented the above scenario but I am struggling on area where "Each thread has a queue of size 5. Here round robin function will check each threads queue and adds task to the thread which has free queue space"

I had been thinking for 2 days where how to implement thread with its own queue which needs to be filled by PriorityBlockingQueue by round robin method.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're doing it this way. The limit on your throughput isn't processing (you haven't mentioned processing the file at all) its bandwidth.  By downloading multiple things at once you're spreading your bandwidth between multiple transfers.  I don't think this would be any faster than a single thread downloading one thing at a time.

Comment: Files in the sense will be mostly images. More so, i need to download images parallel.

Comment: AGain, why?  Your limiting factor will be bandwidth.  Downloading multiple things in parallel won't really help, unless one of the servers is so low in bandwidth that they don't saturate your pipe.  Which is unlikely, especially on mobile.

Comment: If the files are mostly images, why not lazily load the images when you actually need them instead of all at once? [Here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46?category=1) are a bunch of libraries that can help you do that.

Comment: @GabeSechan i agree with you about server-bandwidth limitation, but what if the images size is different, such as 900KB-1.5MB for some, and 200KB-500KB for other, this way the low size images gets a better chance to be loaded faster, as they don't have to wait in a single queue where 5 large size images being queued, does this make sense?

Comment: More over, its one time download and during data sync even small number of resources will be downloaded.